# Facebook OpenGraph image not accepted

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have defined an OpenGraph image at my site (url: https://www.psychotherapiepraxis.at/pt-forum/ ), but the Facebook Object Debugger tells me

> og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big
>   enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and
>   use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook

As the image is 500x500px, I really wonder why it doesn't work? The image should also be accessible for Bots and displays fine if its URL is entered directly into the browser. Any clue on why it isn't accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refreshed the data in the debugger and the error message is gone, but still:

> Use images that are at least 1200 x 630 pixels for the best display on high resolution devices. At the minimum, you should use images that are 600 x 315 pixels to display link page posts with larger images.

...

> Try to keep your images as close to 1.91:1 aspect ratio as possible to display the full image in News Feed without any cropping.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images